# nestjs get method/function caller name or stack

Tags: nestjs

I have a service that has a method (A.method()) which is called by other methods from multiple services (B.method(), C.method()...). 
I want to know somehow what's the method caller name or the service that called my method.

The only working solution I found until know is throwing a dummy error and checking `error.stack`, but this is dirty :)

PS: I'm not using any controller/resolver, just functions that are starting because of cronjobs or constructors. 
I tried interceptors & auth guards but it seems they do not work for simple methods.

Answer (score 0):

I think the error stack is enough information.
If you find the name is ugly, then you should add sourceMap for better function name and file location.
Another approach ( maybe a bit overkill ) is to add tracing like Jaeger or OpenTelemetry to visualize the functions call, execution time and many other information.

Comment: The problem with this solution is that it works with strings, and parsing strings is slowing the app.